# Can't execute script in terminal

Tags: ubuntu-touch, sh

I am a total n00b

I am trying to install Ubuntu on my phone and I am stuck. I can't execute a script in the terminal.

This is the path:
sdcard/Ubuntu/Ubuntu/Ubuntu.sh

Result:

```
Can't execute: permission denied
```

Well, I am rooted,and I have all the system requirements.

I saw another Q on this site (similar but did not help). There,it was suggested to write without extension. When I do that it says

```
path not found
```

Also I tried this:

`chmod 744` (and the path with the script)

After that I tried again to execute and it didn't work

```
Can't execute: permission denied
```

Comment: When you say "I am rooted" do you mean the **phone** is rooted, or you have used the "root" command, `sudo`? Try adding `sudo` before commands. Also, you could execute this script another way, by using `sudo install`.

Comment: The usual issue with executing files directly off external media is that the media's filesystem doesn't support the execute bit, and/or is mounted `noexec`

Comment: @PSmith The phone is rooted

Comment: @steeldriver External media? Do you mean the media that is located on the external SD card? If yes,then "/sdcard" is the internal memory not the external SD card

Comment: @PSmith Added sudo before command and it says :   sh:sudo not found

Comment: I should lose a point for assuming you were trying to run with `sh`. I was working under that assumption, sorry about that. Kudos WK!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set file permission to `744`, only owner may execute the file. Are you owner of the file?

If you want execute shell script without setting script executable (whatever reason), the most reasonable way:

```
$ sh some/script/somewhere/to/run.sh
```

This way you don't have to set executable bit at all. If script is readable, you can execute it.

Comment: Sorry for asking(totally noob) but what do you mean by: some/script/somewhere/to/run.sh.   ?

Comment: The path of the script?

Comment: Yes, the path of the script